# Firebase Security Rules: Validate which fields are allowed in an object

Tags: firebase

I am trying to prevent unwanted fields to be added to my user objects.
--> A user can have a phone and a username (but doesn't have to --> newData.hasChildren(['phone', 'username']) doesn't work here).
I first tried this:

```
"users": {
    "$uid": {
        "$other": {
            ".validate": "['phone', 'username'].indexOf($other) > -1"
        }
    }
}
```

I get an error because of the array :(

So then I thought about doing something like this but it's really not great if I have many potential fields

```
"$other": {
    ".validate": "$other === 'phone' || $other === 'username'"
}
```

Finally, I created a node in my Firebase called 'rules' and did this:

```
"rules": {
    "users": {
        "fields": {
            "phone": true,
            "username": true
        }
    }
}
```

And then my new validation rule in my user object is:

```
"$other": { 
    ".validate": "root.child('rules/users/fields/'+$other).val() === true"
}
```

My question is: Is this a correct way to restrict field names ?

Thank you very much for your answer :) I am pretty new to Firebase but I am having a lot of fun trying it out!

Answer (score 10):

To restrict an object in your Firebase to only have the specified keys, try using one additional wildcard child that will match any attributes not already specified, and reject the write if it contains one of these unmatched attributes:

```
"rules": {
  "users": {
    "$userid": {
      ".validate": "newData.hasChildren(['phone', 'username'])",
      "phone": {
        ".validate": "newData.isNumber()"
      },
      "username": {
        ".validate": "newData.isString()"
      },
      "$other": {
        ".validate": false
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Rob! (and sorry for the late answer, I had read it immediately but forgot to respond :(  )

This is great solution yes, but it just implies having all the potential (but not compulsory) fields listed. But it actually is good:

- I always have some basic validation on them (like newData.isString())
- I was already listing them, just somewhere else :)